# Archiving file in another disk linux

Tags: bash, archive

How do I archive a certain file in another hard disk on linux?

for example I want to archive the files that exist my pwd and are older than two years, I wrote in my bash script:

```
if [ $file -mtime +730 ]; then
```

And now I don't know which command to add in order to archive the file in /dev/sdb1 for example.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The command you show is not complete, so I have no idea what your actual question is

Comment: `in /dev/sdb1` Start by formating the disc so it can store _files_.

Comment: @KamilCuk my question is how would I complete that command in order for it to be able to archive a file that is two years old in another disk , my question was answered now I guess but thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to archive the files that exist my pwd and are older than two years

Consist of two steps:

- finding all files older then two years
- archiving files from step one

To "find" files use `find`. The program `find` takes the argument `-mtime`. Command `[` does not take `-mtime` argument.

"Archiving" I believe is just `cp`. To archive to a *disc*, you first have to format that disc to store *files*, and then you can copy files into the filesystem created on that disc.

Overall, it would something along:

```
 # First format and mount
 # Note - it will erase all the files
 sudo mkfs /dev/sdb1
 sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/somedir
 # then copy
 find . -type f -mtime +730 -print0 |
 xargs -0 cp -a -t /mnt/somedir --parents
```

This uses GNU tools and the `-t` and `--parents` options specific to GNU `cp` - see manual. But you should most probably use `rsync` anyway and research `rdiff-backup` and other better tools to do "archiving".